# In what different terms can Coxeter systems be described?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, geometry, coxeter-groups

My starting point is this question: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/214569
As I understand it they say, that the Coxeter matrix is not sufficient to describe the group.

I thought that up to isomorphism there is a one-to-one correspondence
between Coxeter matrices and Coxeter systems. Or more formal:

Say $(W,S)$ is a Coxeter system determined by a Coxeter matrix $m$. Let $s $ and $s ′$ be distinct elements of $S$. Then:

(i) (The classes of) $s$ and $s′$ are distinct in $W$.

(ii) The order of $ss′$ in $W$ is $m(s,s′)$

The Coxeter matrix defines also the Coxeter graph. So what am I missing? Can someone explain the answers in https://mathoverflow.net/questions/214569

What is the relationship between generators and the matrix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Coxeter matrix defines a Coxeter system which defines a Coxeter group.

However, in the question posed in

> https://mathoverflow.net/questions/214569

one starts with a group $G$ generated by elements, say $\{s_i \mid i \in I\}$, of order two and the orders of the products $s_is_j$ are given to be entries of a Coxeter matrix, $M = (m_{ij})$.  Consequently, there is a surjective homomorphism $W \to G$, where $W$ is the Coxeter group defined by the given Coxeter matrix.  But this homomorphism need not be injective.

Lee Mosher gives a concrete example in his answer to this question.  Here is some additional detail for his answer.  The group $W$ is defined by the Coxeter system $S = \{x,y,z\}$ such that each of $xy$, $yz$, and $zx$ have order 3.  This group is isomorphic to the group of isometries of the Euclidean plane generated by reflections (corresponding to $x$, $y$, and $z$) in the sides of a given equilateral triangle.  Identify $W$ with this subgroup of the isometry group of the Euclidean plane.

Let $N = W \cap T$, where $T$ consists all translations.  Since $T$ is normal in the isometry group (a conjugate of a translation is a translation) of the Euclidean plane, $N$ is normal in $W$.

It is clear that $xN$, $yN$, and $zN$ generate $W/N$ and have order two.  Their products, $xyN$, etc. cannot have order smaller than 3 because $(xy)^2$ is not a translation, and so $xyN$, etc. have order 3 in $W/N$.

Thus, $W \to W/N = G$ is a surjection to a group $G$ generated by involutions such that the product of any two of these involutions has order 3.

Comment: Is it correct, that if $f : S \to G$ has the property $(f(s)f(s^\prime))^{m(s,s^\prime)}=1$ for finite generating sets $S$ then  the surjective homomorphism $f_W : W \to G$ is unique? Thus the lack of injectivity is solely caused by the fact that there exists many different generating sets for the same group?

Comment: Yes, that's the essence of it.  Here's a precise statement: if $\bar{S} \subset G$ has the property that $(\bar{s} \bar{s'})^{m(s,s')} = 1$ for each $\bar{s},\bar{s'} \in \bar{S}$, then there is a unique homomorphism $f:W \to G$ such that $f(s) = \bar{s}$, where $(W,S)$ is the Coxeter system defined by the matrix $(m(s,s'))$.  This is called von Dyck's theorem.  It's a theorem about groups defined by presentations, not a theorem specific to Coxeter systems.  It's not important that $\bar{S}$ generate $G$.